# How to obtain data for warehouse throughput forecasting project?

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, data, forecasting

I am trying to build a machine learning model to predict warehouse throughput. I do not have any domain information or data since I am supposed to build a generic prototype for my clients. I am going to treat it as a multivariate time series problem and have already identified some KPIs like inventory turnover, lead time per order, back order rate, etc.

The problem I am facing is two fold:

1. I hardly see any research papers on how to predict warehouse throughput. The one that is most relevant to my project is: [The Secret Recipe for Modeling Warehouse Throughput](https://dspace.mit.edu/bitstream/handle/1721.1/130971/DeSutter_Gao_Final%20Capstone%20Report_The%20Secret%20Recipe%20for%20Modeling%20Warehouse%20Throughput.pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y)
2. None of the papers I see have used any open source datasets and I have no way of obtaining the data internally as I am building a prototype. I did go a bit further and found that data can be obtained from simulation softwares like AnyLogic.

If anyone can help me with either of these issues that would be great!
The help can be in the form of:

1. Links to any open-source relevant dataset.
2. Someone willing to share a sample data so that I can create synthetic data using that (not sure about how this works considering the trend, seasonality, etc.).
3. Redirect me to any blogs/articles with more information about throughput forecasting.
4. Any other simulation software or methods of obtaining data.
5. Any guidance if you have worked on a similar project before :)

Thank you!

Comment: At which level would you like to modelize your warehouse? Do you have to optimize items' locations for instance?

Comment: To answer the question mentioned by [Nicolas Martin](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/users/119140/nicolas-martin), I need to forecast a number (throughput) per hour, for next 24 hours. Thus, I believe that the data needed would be at hourly granularity. I also think that since it is supposed to be generic, product information would not be relevant but KPIs like lead time, number of live loads, etc. per hour would form the dataset.